# No default signer found when checking the balance of a wallet

Tags: solana

I'm trying to create a solana wallet using solana-keygen and then check it's balance
With this line I create the wallet with the spesific outfile

```
C:\Users\Ali Berkin>solana-keygen new --force -o "C:\Users\Ali Berkin\Documents\Solana\test.json"
```

It generated the wallet successfully and outputted me this

```
Generating a new keypair

For added security, enter a BIP39 passphrase
NOTE! This passphrase improves security of the recovery seed phrase NOT the                                                                                                                                                  
keypair file itself, which is stored as insecure plain text
                                                                                                                                                                  
BIP39 Passphrase (empty for none):                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
Wrote new keypair to C:\Users\Ali Berkin\Documents\Solana\test.json                                                                                               
================================================================================                                                                                  
pubkey: CgvYXNqdVLvNvByFXiSkFGfRC3QFR9SGZq17Bq1bRdht                                                                                                              
================================================================================
```

then I saved this keypair as my default keypair

```
C:\Users\Ali Berkin>solana config set --keypair "C:\Users\Ali 
Berkin\Documents\Solana\test.json"                                                                  
Config File: C:\Users\Ali Berkin\.config\solana\cli\config.yml                                                                                                    
RPC URL: https://metaplex.devnet.rpcpool.com/                                                                                                                     
WebSocket URL: wss://metaplex.devnet.rpcpool.com/ (computed)                                                                                                      
Keypair Path: C:\Users\Ali Berkin\Documents\Solana\test.json                                                                                                      
Commitment: confirmed
```

Finally, when I tried to check my balance, it threw an error which looks like this

```
C:\Users\Ali Berkin>solana balance
Error: Dynamic program error: No default signer found, run "solana-keygen new -o C:\Users\Ali Berkin\Documents\Solana\test.json" to create a new one
```

I already created a keypair at C:\Users\Ali Berkin\Documents\Solana\test.json but error tells me to create one. Can someone help me with this?

Comment: Consider asking this question in the solana stack exchange: https://solana.stackexchange.com/

Comment: thanks for the advice, I asked there too

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apparently, the space on my username caused the problem. I tried opening a new wallet in C:\solana and it seems to work now.

```
C:\solana>solana-keygen new --force -o "C:\solana\test.json"                                                            
Generating a new keypair                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
For added security, enter a BIP39 passphrase                                                                                                                                                                                                    
NOTE! This passphrase improves security of the recovery seed phrase NOT the                                             
keypair file itself, which is stored as insecure plain text                                                                                                                                                                                     
BIP39 Passphrase (empty for none):                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
Wrote new keypair to C:\solana\test.json                                                                                                                       
pubkey: ASgogsZ7WW6uuGQYFX6BwfjwrEytzNJt4f9pVyp9gaaN                                                                                                                                                                                                                                

C:\solana>solana config set --keypair "C:\solana\test.json"                                                             
Config File: C:\Users\Ali Berkin\.config\solana\cli\config.yml                                                          
RPC URL: https://metaplex.devnet.rpcpool.com/                                                                           
WebSocket URL: wss://metaplex.devnet.rpcpool.com/ (computed)                                                            
Keypair Path: C:\solana\test.json                                                                                       
Commitment: confirmed                                                                                                                                                                                                                           

C:\solana>solana balance                                                                                                
0 SOL
```